How to succesfully use Qt library with Windows DLL project?
I have some third party project (SFall- the dll extending original Fallout 2 game). I'd like to add Qt support to the project so i can extend it by some 2d graphic features. I can successfully convert the SFall to Qt supported project and then also successfully compile it, but when I use the newly created ddraw.dll i get this ******* error dialog:

This program requires Windows 95 with DirectX 3.0a or later or Windows
NT version 4.0 with Service Pack 3 or greater


What can be the cause of that error and what can i do to make it to work?
My specs: Win10 DirecxX 12, SFall v4.4.4, MSVC 2019, Qt 5.15.2
Thx. everyone for help!
P.S.
When using the ddraw.dll compiled without Qt support all is OK!
P.S.2
The whole idea of the *SFall *mod is that the generated ddraw.dll is loaded automatically by the original Fallout 2 exe in place of the original dll with this same name (the modified **dll **do it's own job and then, of course loads the original dll)

I'd guess that your dll is failing to load leading to the original dll being loaded instead. My second guess would be that you've not put the qt dlls somewhere fallout can find them

Use dependency walker or dependencies.exe to simulate the DLL loading process and debug loading issues. Even if you do get it to load, expect all kinds of fun crashes from mixing modern code with ancient code.\
